# User authentication against salted passwords in another database

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, postgresql, authentication

My client needs an ASP.NET application built that will have the same users as an existing Ruby on Rails application. It won't be single sign-on. The data from the 'Users' table on the existing database (PostgreSQL) will be copied to the new database (SQL Server). The developers of the existing system will provide all code/support to make the integration work.

1. How would I authenticate users in the new ASP.NET application? Is it just a matter of finding which hashing method/algorithm was used in the RoR application and then using that to validate any forms authentication attempt?
2. How would I synchronize the two 'Users' tables? If either is updated, the other needs to be too. Would I use triggers for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I authenticate users in the new ASP.NET application? Is it just a matter of finding which hashing method/algorithm was used in the RoR application and then using that to validate any forms authentication attempt?

Usually yes.

> How would I synchronize the two 'Users' tables? If either is updated, the other needs to be too. Would I use triggers for this?

From Postgres to SQL-Server, you could write per-row triggers in e.g. pl/perlu, that forward essential changes. In 9.3, you could also use a writable foreign data wrapper, avoiding using an extra pl language in the process. From SQL-Server to Postgres, I'm not 100% but I'm guessing it's possible to do the reverse [in C# or VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179562.aspx).

Alternatively, use two db connections and update the apps' logic accordingly.

Better yet, use an alternative solution for authentication. (I'd be surprised if Rails can't connect to an LDAP directory.)

Comment: What do you mean user two db connections? Ie. each app connects to both databases? That makes the need to duplicate the Users table in the first place seem redundant. How would the ASP.NET app connect to a remote PostgreSQL db? Is it just a matter of enabling remote access on the db and then getting the correct connection string? Forgive me, never done anything outside of the little ASP.NET bubble.

Comment: "That makes the need to duplicate the Users table in the first place seem redundant." -- I'm misunderstanding the question then. Isn't this what you basically wrote here? "The data from the 'Users' table on the existing database (PostgreSQL) will be copied to the new database (SQL Server)."

Comment: You can connect to PostgreSQL using the built-in driver (yes, with the connection string, etc.) or ODBC.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes I didn't consider that the db could allow remote connections, and we have the means to enable that.

Comment: (I want to mark this as the answer).. could you perhaps tell me if implementing the ruby hash in .NET would be complex? 1. Should the function be easy to find for the RoR developers? 2. Would converting it be relatively simple with common sense + google?

Comment: Is it reasonable to request that the RoR developers replace the current method with the one in the question that I linked to? Ie. no need to implement anything new - just use the ASP.NET algo in both apps

Comment: To be honest, my superficial understanding of .Net probably won't be of much more help -- I haven't touched Windows in over a decade. But I wouldn't be surprised if there's a RoR-related gem or library out in there that allows to authenticate users in whichever way you want.